# How can we identify parent branch in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

Suppose i had a main branch -
//project/main/...

and than i created new branch from main -
//project/1.0/...

and then again i created branch from 1.0 -
//project/2.0/...

Now, if someone wants to know from which branch branch 2.0 created, how can user identify?

Answer (score 12):

Select a file and use the Perforce Revision Graph to see the relationships between branches for a particular file.

Perforce does not have Branch as a first-class object, so you have to look at the branch history of individual files.

You could also dump all the branch definitions and try to link the heads and tails of the different branch specifications with a perl script and a graphing tool like GraphViz.

Comment: Note that the Revision Graph is available through the p4v utility which is a GUI, not from the p4 command line utility. Note that there is a -i and a -h option to the p4 filelog command. See p4 help filelog for details.

Comment: @bgoodr Using p4v You can get revision graph of files, but you cannot get a graph of relationship between the branches.

Answer (score 5):

From the command line, doing p4 filelog -i //somefile will show the branch history. It's the command line equivalent of the answer xt1 gave.