# How to list Perforce branches and branch specifications?

Tags: perforce

Perforce documentation suggests that branch specifications can be listed using 'p4 branches' command. As I understand, in Perforce 'branch' and 'branch specifications' are different concepts. So how do I list only branches or branch specifications? Any help?

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/a/5803742/485447, branches aren't first-class objects. So there's not really a simple command to identify all branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'p4 branches' indeed lists all branch specifications.

Branches are collections of files in your repository, identified using a common naming convention.

For example, perhaps you put all your code for product FOO into

> //depot/products/FOO/main/...

And then you make a branch of main called 'r1.0', for your first release, so now you have a branch of your code in

> //depot/products/FOO/r1.0/...

And later you make another branch, called 'r2.0', in

> //depot/products/FOO/r2.0/...

So if you want to view these branches, do:

> p4 dirs //depot/products/FOO/*

You will get a display like:

> //depot/products/FOO/main
>
> //depot/products/FOO/r1.0
>
> //depot/products/FOO/r2.0

This is a nice way to list your branches, but of course it depends on the fact that you used a consistent naming convention to name all your branches.